# HTML textarea styles

Tags: html, css

Let's say within the `<body>` of my web page, all I have is a `<textarea>` element.

This `<textarea>` should be as wide and tall as the browser window (minus any padding or margin the `<body>` has, or any default computed styles per browser).

I can make it as wide as the window by setting `display:block;width:100%`, but it doesn't stretch to the height of the window (see http://jsfiddle.net/4MBAs/) when I include `height:100%`.

How can I stretch the height out to reach the bottom of the browser—without having to use JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set `height:100%;` on `body` and `html` too.

try it like this:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: For me that makes the textarea 100% of the window height, and together with the body padding higher than the window. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Wonderful! Except (and I know this wasn't part of the question), when I *do* add content above this `<textarea>`, the `<textarea>` extends beyond the boundry of the browser view port and scrollbars appear: http://jsfiddle.net/4MBAs/1/. So now, how can I have the `<textarea>` extend to the bottom of the visible area in the browser, and not beyond, when there's content above it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

That does not preserve the body padding, though.